# Python: Appending item to list (string name is same as list name)

Tags: python

I want to append something to a list which has the same (variable) name as a given string.

Background:

I got a comma-separated values file, where val[0] is a value like a list I got actually in Python.

Example code.py:

```py
foo = []
bar = []

with open('csv.txt','r') as fs:
    for line in fs.read().splitlines():
        line=line.split(';')

        line[0].append(data) # where line[0] got the value 'foo' or 'bar'
```

Example csv.txt:

```
foo;some;data
bar;some;other data
```

I know this is bad practice. The file is extra formatted for this code, so there will be no issue (for me). I don't want to use Python 3.10-alpha for match case and I got many lines with `if,elif` statements, which makes my code very illegible.

Anyone know a solution for this? I tried `exec()`, but it don't works.

Comment: So `globals()[line[0]].append()`

Comment: @azro that works perfectly, thank you. I tried this approach, too - but did a syntax mistake.